# OpenNLP tutorial or book

Tags: nlp, reference-request, self-study, books

I am very new to Java and primarily a Python and R user. I want to use [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org) for certain NLP tasks that I have been entrusted with. Is there any good tutorial or book on OpenNLP that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opennlp/index.htm) one, and is very straight forward and easy to follow.

Java is very similar to python in some sense so it shouldn't be a problem for you if you have done OO.

If you want to get deeper inside natural language understanding and processing I recommend [this](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-32967-3) book.